# Getting data value via AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wanted to get the form value that have been serialized and send it via AJAX call

```
var searchData = $("#SearchForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: { 
        thedata : searchData,
        page : "listPage="+pageNumber
    },
    success: function(searchResult){
        $("#search-section").ajaxComplete(function() {
                        $(this).html(searchResult);
        }); 
    }
});
```

What should I do if I wanted to access data in the server side, usually if I only 1 data to be sent, I never define the data in .ajax, like...

```
...
data: searchData,
...
```

And I can access the serialized data in server side just like...

```
$_POST['inputValue1'];
$_POST['inputValue2'];
etc...
```

But how I should do it if I have 2 or more data to send via .ajax, since it must be defined first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use as below

```
 data: searchData+"&listPage="+pageNumber
```

Comment: Thankssssss, Very helping. :D